# Repeat last command in ZSH on OS X Server

Tags: zsh

In bash, to rerun the last command, you can use !!, it prints what it is going to run, then runs it. Observe below:

```
bash-3.2$ echo hello <return>
hello
bash-3.2$ !! <return>
echo hello
hello
bash-3.2$
```

Now, this is how zsh is behaving on my machine, note that that pressing return after !! just prints the command, and does not run it. Is there a way to emulate bash's behaviour in zsh?

```
zsh$  echo hello <return>
hello
zsh$  !! <return>
zsh$  echo hello <return>
hello
zsh$
```

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by the hist_verify option being set to true.

Comment: "setopt No_HIST_VERIFY" is how to turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

Add `setopt No_HIST_VERIFY` to `.zshrc`.

*(I placed it at the bottom of the file)*

To test that it works you can either:

- run `source .zshrc` in the same terminal window
- or open a new terminal window